# Django: keep lazy translation when composing translated strings

Tags: django, internationalization, translation, gettext, lazy-evaluation

In Django, I'm happily using `ugettext_lazy` to pospone the translation of a string only when its representation is needed.

The problem is that when I concatenate a lazy string to a normal string or when I use its methods (e.g. capitalize() ), the string is evaluated and I loose lazy translation.

E.g.

```
label = ugettext_lazy('my label')   #This is lazy
label_concat = label + ' some other string'   #'label_concat' contains transalted 'label'
label_cap = label.capitalize()  #'label_cap' contains transalted 'label'

#Set language
...

print label    #Translated
print label_cap  #Not translated
```

I know that this is the normal behaviour of Django but I wonder if someone has resolved this issue.

Comment: For django 1.11 and further. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29252312/how-can-i-join-lazy-translation-in-django/47263039#47263039

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For concatenating, you can use [`string_concat`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#joining-strings-string-concat) (up to 1.10)/[`format_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/#formatting-strings-format-lazy) (from 1.11) which creates a lazy object

If you wish to implement lazy `capitalize`, use `django.utils.functional.lazy` decorator. See `string_concat` [implementation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11.8/django/utils/translation/__init__.py#L227).