# How can I join lazy translation in Django?

Tags: python, django, translation, django-i18n

I need to use lazy translation but also I need to make translation - how to deal with?

This code is doing what I need:

```
print ugettext_lazy('Hello world!')
```

Now I want join two lazy translations together and translate it separately (I now that will not work and why but want to have two translation strings).

```
print ugettext_lazy('Hello world!') + ' ' + ugettext_lazy('Have a fun!')
```

I can do such code but it generates more translation than is need.

```
print ugettext_lazy('Hello world! Have a fun!')
```

Is it possible to have two translation strings and lazy translation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since django 1.11 [`string-concat`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.string_concat) is deprecated, and [`format_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.format_lazy) should be used instead

```
from django.utils.text import format_lazy
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy

name = ugettext_lazy('John Lennon')
instrument = ugettext_lazy('guitar')
result = format_lazy('{} : {}', name, instrument)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, otherwise it would result in another string being translated...

Here's an example taken from the docs. There's no mention on joining 2 translation files in one, so I assume it cannot be done, but I can be wrong.

This is the correct way of doing it

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#joining-strings-string-concat

```
from django.utils.translation import string_concat
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy
...
name = ugettext_lazy('John Lennon')
instrument = ugettext_lazy('guitar')
result = string_concat(name, ': ', instrument)
```