# Django 2.1 error while executing makemigrations

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am on my way to move to Django 2.1.5 with Python 3.7 from Django 1.6.0 with Python 2.7 and encountered an error while executing `python manage.py makemigrations myapp`. Could anyone give me a hint to solve, please? I probably need to modify the model but am not sure what I should start with.

```
Migrations for 'model':
  model/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model XXXX
    - Create model YYYY
    - Create model ZZZZ
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 7, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 184, in handle
    self.write_migration_files(changes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 222, in write_migration_files
    migration_string = writer.as_string()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 151, in as_string
    operation_string, operation_imports = OperationWriter(operation).serialize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 110, in serialize
    _write(arg_name, arg_value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 62, in _write
    arg_string, arg_imports = MigrationWriter.serialize(item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 279, in serialize
    return serializer_factory(value).serialize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 37, in serialize
    item_string, item_imports = serializer_factory(item).serialize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 197, in serialize
    return self.serialize_deconstructed(path, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 85, in serialize_deconstructed
    arg_string, arg_imports = serializer_factory(arg).serialize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 37, in serialize
    item_string, item_imports = serializer_factory(item).serialize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 37, in serialize
    item_string, item_imports = serializer_factory(item).serialize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 293, in serializer_factory
    value = str(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 113, in __text_cast
    return func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
TypeError: gettext() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I will try to put more detailed information about the model if needed.

Comment: Theres a problem with the use of `gettext` (translations) somewhere in your models, but it's impossible to tell more from the traceback alone. Look for the `gettext` calls in your models (nb: `gettext` might have been aliased to `_` - this is a very common convention), one of them has been passed two arguments when only one is expected.

Comment: Also, `getext` should only be used in functions code - for code at the top-level or class-level (including in models fields definitions), you want `gettext_lazy`.

Comment: I found gettext_lazy caused the problem in my code. I just followed this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29252312/how-can-i-join-lazy-translation-in-django and successfully migrated! Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

Dump all the database before applying the below technique.

Remove all migrations files and also folders then re-run your command.

Also, compare existing function used in Django 1.6.0 to 2.1.5 in Django documentation.

Comment: Do NOT thank him for the tip, it's actually the worse idea ever. Migrations are part of your code base, and if you delete them before all have been applied on all deployments of your project, you won't be able to update those deployments.

Comment: I don't know how u comment that  I already told that line 

Dump all the database before applying the below technique. I also know this is not the right way. Please read the statement then comment on it.Thanks